# Retrieve closest upper values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi and thanks in advance for your time.

I have to solve this specific problem.
and I have following table of stamps

```
idStamp     idCustomer  uptoW       uptoD       price
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
218         4           2200        690         205
218         4           1700        660         155
```

I need to find a single row (if exist) that match 4 criteria:
    - idStamp
    - idCustomer
    - uptoW
    - uptoD

I have used

```
SELECT Distinct(UptoW) FROM [mytable]
WHERE uptoW=(SELECT MIN(uptoW)
FROM [mytable]
WHERE uptoW >= 1600-1 AND idStamp = 218 AND idCustomer = 4)
```

and it works for 3 criteria
    - idStamp
    - idCustomer
    - uptoW

But I can't figure how to implement the fourth matching criteria.

summarizing
Using following param (idStamp=218, idCustomer=4, Width=1600, Depth=640)
I expect to find the row with price 155
...but...
using param (idStamp=218, idCustomer=4, Width=1600, Depth=670)
I expect to find the row with price 205
If theres' no way to satisfy all criteria, I expect no rows.

-- edit 2013.12.13 --

```
idStamp     idCustomer  UptoW       UptoD       price      
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
218         4           220         69          155        
218         4           170         100         205        
218         4           230         100         400        
218         4           180         90          345        
218         4           180         89          34         
218         4           179         90          32         
218         4           179         89          2343       

DECLARE @p_idStamp INT = 218
,@p_idCustomer INT = 4
,@UptoW INT = 160
,@UptoD INT = 89
,@UptoWmin int
,@UptoDmin int;

SELECT @UptoWmin = MIN(UptoW) FROM mytable<br>
WHERE UptoW =(SELECT MIN(UptoW) FROM mytable<br>
WHERE UptoW >= @UptoW-1 AND idStamp = 218 AND idCustomer = 4)<br>

SELECT @UptoDmin = MIN(UptoD) FROM mytable<br>
WHERE UptoD =(SELECT MIN(UptoD) FROM mytable<br>
WHERE UptoD >= @UptoD-1 AND idStamp = 218 AND idCustomer = 4)<br>

SELECT TOP(1) * FROM mytable<br>
WHERE UptoW >= @UptoWmin AND UptoD >= @UptoDmin<br>
ORDER BY UptoW, UptoD<br>

SELECT TOP(1) * FROM mytable<br>
WHERE UptoW >= @UptoWmin AND UptoD >= @UptoDmin<br>
ORDER BY UptoD, UptoW<br>
```

I have probably found a solution.
As you can see I first search the exact min values in the table
then I compose a query that satisfy both params.
I repeat the query inverting the order by clause, becouse results can differ.

Let me know if better solution can be adopted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one way of doing what you want is ordering the results by the *exceeding area*, and then taking the first row.

Something like that:

```
-- Test schema, based on S Koppenol answer:
CREATE TABLE stamps (
    [idStamp]    INT,
    [idCustomer] INT,
    [uptoW]      INT,
    [uptoD]      INT,
    [price]      MONEY
)

INSERT INTO stamps (
    [idStamp], [idCustomer], [uptoW], [uptoD], [price]
) VALUES
    (218, 4, 2200, 690, 205.0),
    (218, 4, 1700, 660, 155.0)
GO

-- Procedure to find the desired row:
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRow(
    @idStamp    INT,
    @idCustomer INT,
    @uptoW      INT,
    @uptoD      INT
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
        T.idStamp,
        T.idCustomer,
        T.uptoW,
        T.uptoD,
        (T.uptoW * T.uptoD - @uptoW * @uptoD) AS DELTA_AREA
    FROM
        stamps T
    WHERE
        T.uptoW       >= @uptoW + 1
        AND T.uptoD   >= @uptoD + 1
        AND idStamp    = @idStamp
        AND idCustomer = @idCustomer
    ORDER BY
        DELTA_AREA
END
GO

-- Testing  
EXEC GetRow 218, 4, 1600, 640; 
EXEC GetRow 218, 4, 1700, 640;
EXEC GetRow 218, 4, 1600, 660;
EXEC GetRow 218, 4, 2200, 660;
```

And the testing results:

```
idStamp     idCustomer  uptoW       uptoD       DELTA_AREA
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
218         4           1700        660         98000

(1 row(s) affected)

idStamp     idCustomer  uptoW       uptoD       DELTA_AREA
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
218         4           2200        690         430000

(1 row(s) affected)

idStamp     idCustomer  uptoW       uptoD       DELTA_AREA
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
218         4           2200        690         462000

(1 row(s) affected)

idStamp     idCustomer  uptoW       uptoD       DELTA_AREA
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

That way you'll surely get a record that is not only inside the requested limit, but also the nearest.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `uptoD >= DESIRED_VALUE` to the validation.

For example:

```
SELECT Distinct(UptoW) FROM [stamps]
WHERE uptoW=(SELECT MIN(uptoW)
FROM [stamps]
WHERE uptoW >= 1600-1 AND uptoD >= 640 AND idStamp = 218 AND idCustomer = 4);
```

This would give you:

```
UPTOW
1700
```

But you could simplify further and do:

```
SELECT MIN(uptoW) AS UPTOW
FROM [stamps]
WHERE uptoW >= 1600-1 
  AND uptoD >= 640 
  AND idStamp = 218 
  AND idCustomer = 4
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b997/6)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Filipe, your solution work only partialy becouse I have to limit to the max also the uptoD. In the example I posted there are only 2 rows, so the result is ok, but with more records, the result is not the expected. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @RickyReds. Could you be a little more specific? add to sqlfiddle one example where the query doesn't work please

Comment: Hi, with more than 2 rows in the table you can have more than one result, and non necessarily the smallest one because of "uptoD >= 640".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the desired end result, but I think this will come close. This will give you the record with the lowest *uptoW* (if any) that matches all criteria.

```
DECLARE @p_idStamp INT = 218
,@p_idCustomer INT = 4
,@p_uptoW INT = 1600
,@p_uptoD INT = 640;

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM mytable
WHERE idStamp = @p_idStamp
AND idCustomer = @p_idCustomer
AND uptoW > @p_uptoW
AND uptoD > @p_uptoD
ORDER BY uptoW ASC;
```